# How Does One Test IIS7's OrphanWorkerProcess (along with OrphanActionExe and OrphanActionParams)?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, application-pools

What's a valid way to test IIS7's **OrphanWorkerProcess** settings are working?  I have a script and all the settings in the configuration for my application pool.  However, it seems just simply recycling the application pool does not do the trick.  I've even validated that the script is never attempted to load by using **ProcessMon**.

I'm basically trying to do something similar to this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828222

Here's the IIS 7 reference page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386513(v=VS.90).aspx

I think the problem I'm having may be I was simply expecting the process to be orphaned when I recycled the application pool, but that doesn't work.  The reference says:

> *"Specifies whether to assign a worker process to an orphan state instead of terminating it **when an application pool fails.**"*

So maybe the real question is possibly:

- How do I invoke a failure to see if the script I have set for the **orphanActionExe** is working?

Answer (score 2):

Use Process Explorer from SysInternals. It has a feature to suspend a process allowing it to pause communication with WAS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it fail communication with WAS somehow. If pinging is enabled, you could try attaching a debugger and pausing the process; haven't tried it.

It doesn't happen on regular recycles, just when a reactive recycling event is encountered.